# Name collisions in data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

```
> str(tester)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  6402 obs. of  2419 variables:

$ h1           : int  1 5 6 12 13 16 19 22 26 28 ...
$ joinno       : int  2 6 7 11 12 14 16 17 19 21 ..
$ h1           : int  1 5 6 12 13 16 19 22 26 28 ...
$ joinno       : int  2 6 7 11 12 14 16 17 19 21 ...
```

Could somebody enlighten me as to how/why cbind-ing these two objects together with identical column names doesn't cause problems?  These happen to actually be identical columns so it's kind of moot but when I subset that column name(s) I get a single value.  So how does R decide which column I'm referring to (presumably the first)?  Is there an easy/canned way to de-dupe columns in R?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you should check the documentation for `data.table`; there's an argument there like `chk.names`, which is analogous to and option in base R functions. As far as dedupping goes, I guess you could/should handle that when you create the object.

Answer (score 1):

@Frank is right. The defaults are `check.names=TRUE` for `?data.frame` and `check.names=FALSE` for `?data.table`. Although, in the case of `cbind`-ing, it doesn't come into play:

```
cbind(data.frame(a=1),data.frame(a=2))
cbind(data.table(a=1),data.table(a=2))
```

...both give duplicate names. You could apply:

```
names(out) <- make.unique(names(out))
```

...after `cbind`-ing to fix it up. Another option would be to not use `cbind` in favour of:

```
data.frame(data.frame(a=1),data.frame(a=2))
data.table(data.table(a=1),data.table(a=2),check.names=TRUE)
```